# Problem installing Drupal 6.22 with Drush

Tags: drush

I'm trying to install Drupal 6.22 with Drush 4.4 on my CentOS 5.6 box, but am having problems getting it to work.

I run the following command:

```
drush dl drupal-6.22 --drupal-project-rename=drupal1
```

Then I run:

```
drush status
```

and get:

```
 Drupal version         :  6.22                  
 Default theme          :  garland               
 Administration theme   :  garland               
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini          
 Drush version          :  4.4                   
 Drush configuration    :                        
 Drush alias files      :                        
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html/drupal1
```

Which seems to suggest that all was downloaded properly.

Then I run the following command to start setting it up:

```
drush site-install standard --account-name=admin --account-pass=REMOVED --db-url=mysql://admin:REMOVED@localhost/drupal1db
```

It asks me if I want to continue and I choose 'yes'. After a second or two, it returns me to the command line prompt.

Then I run 'drush status' again, which returns the following error:

Table 'drupal1db.access' doesn't exist                [warning]
query: SELECT 1 FROM access WHERE type = 'host' AND
LOWER('127.0.0.1') LIKE LOWER(mask) AND status = 0 LIMIT 0,
1 database.mysql.inc:135
Table 'drupal1db.cache' doesn't exist                 [warning]
query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache
WHERE cid = 'variables' database.mysql.inc:135
Table 'drupal1db.variable' doesn't exist              [warning]
query: SELECT * FROM variable database.mysql.inc:135
Table 'drupal1db.cache' doesn't exist                 [warning]
query: UPDATE cache SET data = '', created = 1309816902,
expire = 0, headers = '', serialized = 0 WHERE cid =
'variables' database.mysql.inc:135
Table 'drupal1db.system' doesn't exist                [warning]
query: SELECT name, filename, throttle FROM system WHERE type =
'module' AND status = 1 AND bootstrap = 1 ORDER BY weight
ASC, filename ASC database.mysql.inc:135
Table 'drupal1db.url_alias' doesn't exist             [warning]
query: SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM url_alias database.mysql.inc:135
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function filter_xss() in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc on line 655
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Call to undefined function filter_xss() in
/var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc, line 655

I go to the Drupal directory in my browser and it just shows a blank white page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when trying to install Drupal 6.26 with drush 4.5 and 5.0 (I tried both).

You do not have to create the database.  You can but drush will drop it and re-create it.

I fixed my problem by doing :

```
drush site-install default --db-url=mysql://drupaldbuser:REMOVED@localhost/drupal-6-25
```

I used the profile `default` rather than `standard` since drupal 6.x uses `default` as the default profile.  The `standard` profile is the new default name in Drupal 7.

- http://drupal.org/node/1410242#comment-5795114
- http://knol.google.com/k/how-to-install-drupal-with-drush

Answer (score 4):

given the "doesn't exist" errors you're seeing, i'll ask -- have you in fact created the DB, and aassigned proper permissions?

just for reference, although on Drupal 7 with Drush 5x (not sure it's the same for older Drupal & Drush), this works for me.

1st create the DB manually,

```
mysqladmin create my_D7_db
```

assign permissions,

```
mysql
  mysql> GRANT CREATE, DROP, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, INSERT, INDEX, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON `my_D7_db`.* TO 'my_D7_dbadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 quit
```

then exec the Drupal install,

```
drush site-install standard -y --site-name=www.mysite.com --site-mail=me@myemailhost.com --account-name=my_D7_admin --account-pass=my_D7_admin_password --db-url=mysql://my_D7_dbadmin:my_password@localhost/my_D7_db --db-prefix=my_D7_
```

immediately after this, the site's available, assuming your webserver's properly pointed at the Drupal root, at:

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

maybe give that a try?

Comment: Hi Richard,

Yes, I've created the DB and assigned it privileges - through PHPMyAdmin.

I'll give it a go through the command line, though, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

In certain distributions, like Acquia, the default profile does not exist, and `drush site-install` fails. In this example, the following code will work:

```
drush si acquia --db-url=mysql://user:password@localhost/db -y
```